# Same Domain SAML Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, saml, adfs

I have some web application in my server which use ADFS for authentication let's say this is their URLs :

```
http://myServer/ManyWebApps/WebApp1
http://myServer/ManyWebApps/WebApp2
http://myServer/ManyWebApps/WebApp3
```

When the user access any URL under "ManyWebApps" hierarchy he can freely use the server function they provide through javascript and through the browser without further authentication:

```
http://myServer/ManyWebApps/Server/Function
```

Now, I need to detach one of my web apps to a new URL like so :

```
http://myServer/WebApp1
```

Will the user still be able to free access server functions under the "ManyWebApps" hierarchy :

```
access http://myServer/ManyWebApps/Server/Function from http://myServer/WebApp1
```

Note : both web applications are still on the same server and work with the same ADFS server, when the user enters http://myServer/WebApp1 he is authenticated, but will he be able to access functions on diffirent web apps on the server without further authentication?

P.S : I need to access a function without further authentication because making an AJAX request to the function  while unauthenticated will cause the AJAX request to be redirected to the ADFS which it can't handle

Answer (score 0):

CONFIRMED : The authentication is saved in http://myServer so no further authentication need to take place if both apps are on the same domain

When sending a request to the server, all of the user's cookies are sent including the authentication token. If the user's doesn't have the token in his cookies, the server will direct him to the ADFS. But since both web applications are under the same server, they share the same cookies which means once the user entered any address in MyServer hierarchy, he can free enter any in that hierarchy without further authentication